# I need to filter date based on "roomCategories" in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I need to filter date based on "roomCategories" in React JS
and result expecting

selectCategory['JSA - Junior suite: All Inclusive','JCV - Junior suite courtyard view: All Inclusive'];

My Code is

```
state = {
        selectCategory: [],
        count: 0
    };
```

```
roomCategories : ['jsa','jcv'];

roomCategoriesData: [
            { id: 'jsa', value: 'jsa', label: 'JSA - Junior suite: All Inclusive' },
            { id: 'jcv', value: 'jcv', label: 'JCV - Junior suite courtyard view: All Inclusive' },
            { id: 'osk', value: 'osk', label: 'OSK - Oceanview : All Inclusive' },
            { id: 'jsh', value: 'jsh', label: 'JSH - Junior suite oceanfront - All Inclusive' },
            { id: 'ipa', value: 'ipa', label: 'IPA - Junior suite partial ocean view : All Inclusive' },
        ],
```

and my React JS code is

```
render() {
        
        const { data, roomCategoriesData } = this.props;        

        const { selectCategory, count } = this.state;
        const length = data?.roomCategories.length; 

        if (count < length) {
            data.roomCategories.map((item) => {                
               
                roomCategoriesData.map((catItem) => {
                    ;
                    if(item == catItem.value) {
                        
                        this.setState({
                            selectCategory: [...this.state.selectCategory, catItem.label]
                        });
                        
                    }
                });
                this.setState({
                    count: this.state.count + 1
                });
                                
            });
        }
```

but the result is

```
selectCategory['JCV - Junior suite courtyard view: All Inclusive', 'JCV - Junior suite courtyard view: All Inclusive'];
```

expected result should be

```
selectCategory['JSA - Junior suite: All Inclusive','JCV - Junior suite courtyard view: All Inclusive'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve your data between arrays using find and filter methods I have prepared a working example for you [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lajmsx?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Really Thanks. You solved this problem.Thanks.